# Oracle calculated column store select result

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 select location , 
name as  ( select  name from tbd b
Join tbt  t on  t.id =. b.id  where x= 456 )
From customer
```

I'm trying the above 
How can add result of another query as calculated column to main query

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  As stated, the question really makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking to write a subquery like this:

```
select 
    location,
    (select 
        name 
    from tbd b Join tbt t
        on t.id = b.id 
    where x= 456) as name
From customer;
```

Note here that the subquery must select only one column and should return at most one row.

Also note that if correlated with the outer query, the query is likely to run slow. You might want to add more details in the question about what you're are trying to do.

Comment: `these kind of SQL queries are likely to run slow` ... why do you say that? It's not necessarily true, especially if the query can take advantage of scalar subquery caching. Looking at the OP's example, it's highly likely that the scalar subquery will run once and then just use the cached result, since it's not correlated to the customer table (although whether the OP's example is representative of their actual problem is anyone's guess!)

Comment: @Boneist You're absolutely right. I said *likely* because I thought that OP wants a correlated query. I assume things when questions are not clear :P.